# passing an image to the next view

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

i managed to make the user choose an image from his gallery when he clicks the button, but how do i move to the next view when the user choose an image?

here is my code of choosing an image from the gallery

```
 @IBAction func gallery(sender: AnyObject) {

        var image = UIImagePickerController()
        //image.delegate = self
        image.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
        image.allowsEditing = false

        self.presentViewController(image, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
```

when i take out the comment, an error shows saying

```
cannot assign a value of type 'postChoices' to a value of type 'protocol<UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>?
```

what am trying to do here is to go to the next view when a picture is chosen from the gallery and view it in the other view

Comment: Have you implemented the delegate methods? And also conformed to the UIImagePickerControllerDelegate protocol?

Comment: @Vijayts no i haven't, can u guide me on how to do it please

Answer (score 0):

```
//Add Delegate to ur View Controller UIImagePickerControllerDelegate
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate 

//Create Variable
var controller: UIImagePickerController?

//Delegate Methods
func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker: UIImagePickerController!) {
println("Picker was cancelled")
picker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController!,
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]!){

  println("Picker returned successfully")

}
```

//And View did load method

```
 controller = UIImagePickerController()

  if let theController = controller{

        theController.delegate = self
        theController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
        theController.allowsEditing = false

    presentViewController(theController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: I think the OP wanted an answer in Swift.

Comment: Am using swift, if you can give me the answer in swift i will appreciate it

Comment: @muku thanks, but am confused, where should i put this code? just another function in the same class

Comment: @muku what is this line do class ViewController: UIViewController,, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate

Comment: @muku what is kUTTypeImage?, sorry for my questions, its quite confusing, i don't have much knowledge in swift

Comment: sorry that code is for diff purpose,check edit answer

Comment: @muku okay, i will try implementing it now

Comment: @muku lets say if i managed to choose an image from the first view controller and pass it to the second view controller, how can i then go to the second view controller, i couldn't make the same button that makes u choose an image from the gallery, to take u to the second view controller as well

Comment: @muku the controller in the code u sent me above is unresolved identifier O_o